# GitHub: What is the difference having these two groups of branch protection settings enabled?

Tags: github

Upon reviewing the branch protection settings for a GitHub repo, and reading the documentation for all of the settings, I still can't quite figure out the difference between enabling these two groups of settings:

[image]

According to the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/about-protected-branches#require-pull-request-reviews-before-merging), if I require approvals, it means an approval is required from someone else (I cannot approve my own PR):

> If you enable required reviews, collaborators can only push changes to a protected branch via a pull request that is approved by the required number of reviewers with write permissions.

The next option seems self explanatory, but here is what the documentation has to say about it:

> Optionally, you can choose to dismiss stale pull request approvals when commits are pushed. If anyone pushes a commit that modifies code to an approved pull request, the approval will be dismissed, and the pull request cannot be merged. This doesn't apply if the collaborator pushes commits that don't modify code, like merging the base branch into the pull request's branch.

However, when I look at the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/about-protected-branches#require-pull-request-reviews-before-merging) for the branch protection setting to "require approval of the most recent push", it sounds like it does the same thing as if I had the first two enabled:

> Optionally, you can require approvals from someone other than the last person to push to a branch before a pull request can be merged. This ensures more than one person sees pull requests in their final state before they are merged into a protected branch. If you enable this feature, the most recent user to push their changes will need an approval regardless of the required approvals branch protection. Users who have already reviewed a pull request can reapprove after the most recent push to meet this requirement.

It sounds like this option implies that an approval will be dismissed if a new commit is pushed to the branch for the open PR. If that's the case, then isn't enabling the first to the same as enabling the last one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "require approval of the most recent push" protection rule was recently introduced (oct 2022), with the express purpose to prevent [someone responding to a code review request from sneaking in changes and approving them themselves or using the already supplied approval from another reviewer](https://www.legitsecurity.com/blog/bypassing-github-required-reviewers-to-submit-malicious-code).

The security research that explores these topics has not been broadly published, but there are some [great discussions with recommendations on how to secure your branches](https://medium.com/boostsecurity/slsa-dip-source-of-the-problem-a1dac46a976).

With this new policy enabled, when a reviewer applies some suggestions to the code, they can't approve and merge the code without finding another person to review their changes.

Excerpts from the article, red team, emphasis mine:

> — Modify code after review
>
> After the attacker submits a valid and good code change that is approved, the attacker abuses their existing approval to make further changes that include bad code while retaining the stale approval.
>
> **Another scenario is that the attacker could first be a good samaritan and approve the code of a fellow developer, let’s assume it’s a good code change, but it doesn’t matter. What matters is that once they have approved that pull request, they could abuse their own write access, add bad code and self-approve their own code change.**

And the protections, blue team, emphasis mine:

> Require a pull request before merging
>
> - Require approvals
> - Dismiss stale pull request approvals when new commits are pushed
> - Require review from Code Owners
> - Allow specified actors to bypass required pull requests (avoid unless you absolutely need to)
> - **Require approval of the most recent push (this is a new setting, as of October 2022, and is really great mitigation for some of our attack scenarios)**
> - Require status checks to pass before merging (it you have some form of CI with tests, linters, SAST, it would be great to enforce those)
> - Require signed commits (this is great for end-to-end accountability)
> - Enforce Branch Protection for administrator (i.e. “Do not allow bypassing the above settings”)

Recommended mitigations, emphasis mine:

> — Modify code after review
>
> Attacker submits good code, gets approval, then submits bad code
>
> - The mitigation is to set your Branch Protection to “Dismiss stale pull request approvals when new commits are pushed”.
>
> **Attacker approves someone else’s good code, then submits bad code and self-approves changes**
>
> - **The mitigation is to set your Branch Protection to “Require approval of the most recent push”.**

Comment: Super! I was about to say, you pretty much provided a whole answer in the comments. I will mark this as accepted.

Comment: Yeah, needed the time to make sure I was making sense. There's not much documentation on these new policies. New Tag protection rules are also for similar protections.

Comment: Here is an edge case that I find problematic recently though: 

1. Reviewer approves
2. Reviewer clicks “update branch” to pull in latest changes from target branch
3. Now the pr is no longer in an approved state, and a 3rd actor is required